# Expressing a "generalisation" of Gamma function in terms of known special functions.

Tags: analysis, special-functions

It is known that an integral of the form
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} x^\beta \, dx $$
for $\beta > -1$ can be expressed in terms of a Gamma function. I am interested in the integral
$$I(\alpha,\beta) = \int_0^\infty e^{i \alpha x -x^2} x^\beta \, dx $$
and whether it can be expressed in terms of any known special functions. Here $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Of course, if $\beta$ was a positive integer one could express $I(\alpha,\beta)$ in terms of derivatives an error function. This is because you could write
$$I(\alpha,\beta) = (-i)^\beta \frac{d^\beta}{d\alpha^\beta}\int_0^\infty e^{i \alpha x -x^2} \, dx$$
and $\int_0^\infty e^{i \alpha x -x^2} \, dx$ can be written as a (complex) error function. However it is the case of non-integer $\beta$ that interests me.

Comment: I believe it will be a sort of Bessel function, for general $\beta$. Would that be a useful response for you?

Comment: Yes that would be useful!

Comment: Since I myself would need to crib from either my own notes or from Wikipedia, to get the conventions and constants exactly right for further reference, it might be best for me to refer you to Wikipedia on "Bessel functions", especially "modified Bessel functions", the K-Bessel function. One of the integral representations appearing there is the same as yours after changing variables...

Comment: @paulgarrett There is a closed form in terms of $_1 F_1$, but I don't quite see how we can get a Bessel or a modified Bessel function. To get to $_1 F_1$, we can expand $e^{i \alpha x}$ into power series and integrate termwise. Since we get $\Gamma(k/2 + a)/k!$ factors, we consider the sums over $k = 2 l$ and $k = 2 l + 1$ and apply the duplication formula to $(2 l)!$ and $(2 l + 1)!$. That gives two hypergeometric series.